# How to deal with varying indentation in ReStructuredText codeblocks?

Tags: restructuredtext

I am converting an older document into ReST. The [document](https://iraf.net/irafdocs/beguide.pdf) has the following construction:

[image]

Question is now how to get this with ReST. The following does *not* work:

```
[…] are listed below.

::

      dataio - Data format conversion package (RFITS, etc.)     
        dbms - Database management package (not yet implemented)   
             …
      system - System utilities package             
   utilities - Miscellaneous utilities package

A package must be loaded in order […]
```

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about raw docutils, but at least Sphinx has a [code-block directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html?highlight=code-block#directive-code-block) that has better control on the indentation I think.

On the other hand, I have seen other people use [csv tables](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#csv-table) to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [rST specification](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#indented-literal-blocks),
the given example should (and does) work, if all lines are more indented than the "literal block marker" `::`.¹

To fix the following non working example

```
#. ::

      dataio - Data format conversion package (RFITS, etc.)
        dbms - Database management package (not yet implemented)
  
      system - System utilities package
   utilities - Miscellaneous utilities package
```

just indent all lines by at least one more space.

¹ tested with Docutils 0.19